# ошибка MutationObserver

Tags: javascript

хочу сделать что бы #yikes-mailchimp-container-1 p удалялся через 5 секунд спустя появление.
Что нужно доделать в этом алгоритме?

Показывает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

```
// Выбираем целевой элемент
var target = document.querySelector('#yikes-mailchimp-container-1 p');
// Конфигурация observer (за какими изменениями наблюдать)
const config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
};

// Колбэк-функция при срабатывании мутации
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.querySelector("#yikes-mailchimp-container-1 p").remove();
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
};

// Создаём экземпляр наблюдателя с указанной функцией колбэка
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Начинаем наблюдение за настроенными изменениями целевого элемента
observer.observe(target, config);

// Позже можно остановить наблюдение
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: Не совсем понятны начальные условия. Если вы пытаетесь поймать время создания элемента, нужно мониторить не сам элемент, которого ещё нет, но его возможного родителя или предка.

Comment: Да, мне надо именно так. Что ещё нужно изменить кроме этого условия?

Comment: Ошибка из заголовка как раз потому, что вы пытаетесь ослеживать несуществующий объект. Можно убрать атрибуты из отслеживания - для вашей цели  `childList` и `subtree` достаточно (а если вы можете чётко определить родителя будущего элемента, можно ограничится `childList`). Проверяйте появляющиеся элементы (`MutationRecord.addedNodes`) при помощи, например, [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Answer (score 2):

ошибка *Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.*

Явно говорит, что первым параметром передан не узел.

Это свидетельствует о том, что переменной `target`

```
// Выбираем целевой элемент
var target = document.querySelector('#yikes-mailchimp-container-1 p');
```

Присвоилось значение `null`. Это может быть из-за того, что элемента с указанным `id` нет на странице. Либо он появляется на ней, позже присваивания значения переменной.